# Creating the tribonacci numbers in Clojure

Tags: clojure

I was wondering if someone would be able to help me create a function that would given a number would return the tribonacci number that corresponds to that number for example 
10 would return 44
15 would return 927

Answer (score 1):

Generally, you should show what you have already tried and then let us know what problem you are having, so we can point you to a fix. Asking Stack Overflow to do this for you from scratch is poor manners.

But, I love Clojure and these problems are fun. First of all, there are so many ways to do this, and just googling Clojure fibonacci will get you started in many many different directions for this.

Here is a quick example using `reduce`:

```
(defn tri [x] 
   (last (reduce 
            (fn [[a b c] n] 
               (conj [b c] (+ a b c))) [0 0 1] (range (- x 3)))))
```

You could also use `iterate`:

`(nth (iterate (fn [[a b c]] [b c (+ a b c)]) [0 0 1]) 5)`

This returns the 5th from the first set of tribonacci numbers, where `[0 0 1]` is the initial set.

To get an exact result from X'th index, also wrap it in a function as above, like so:

```
(defn tri-iterate [x] 
   (last 
     (nth (iterate (fn [[a b c]] [b c (+ a b c)]) [0 0 1]) (- x 3))))
```

You can do this in many other ways as well.